# Merge or join dataframes on numerical condition

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframes which I'd like to join based on equivalence in one column, and based on a numeric difference in the second column.

For example:

```
d = {'col1': [A, B], 'col2': [30, 40]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d1 = {'col1': [A, B], 'col2': [35, 400]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)


   col1  col2
0     A     30
1     B     40

   col1  col2
0     A     35
1     B     400
```

Is there a way to merge on equivalence in col1, and a condition such as "absolute difference in col2 < 10"?

The only solutions I have seen discussed involve a general merge, on col1, and creating a filter based on the difference in col2.

Comment: What would you expect your result to be for a merge on these two frames?

Comment: Hi @HenryEcker - as hamza's final output below.  Only I'd like to do it in one step.

Answer (score 1):

Since the expected shape of output wasn't defined in the question so i concatenated both dataframes vertically based on the given condition.

```
d1 = {'col1': ["A", "B"], 'col2': [30, 40]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2 = {'col1': ["A", "B"], 'col2': [35, 400]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

out=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1,ignore_index = True)
out = out.rename(columns = {0: "df1_col1",1: "df1_col2",2: "df2_col1",3: "df2_col2"})
out = out[abs(out["df1_col2"] - out["df2_col2"]) <10]
print(out)

        df1_col1  df1_col2  df2_col1  df2_col2
    0        A        30        A        35
```

Comment: hi @hamza, if I got you right, you are first joining the full dfs and then filtering on the condition.  I would like to know if a join is possible only on that condition.